# Check for pattern in a non-blocking manner using PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread, pyqt6, qtserialport

I have a method `command(self, command, data)`, part of a `class CommandProcessor` that checks a buffer for a specific pattern and then **returns** it content:

```
 command(self, message):
     serial_port.write(bytes(message))
     attempt = 3
     while attempt > 0:
         sleep(1)
         response = self.check_response()
         if type(response) == list or response == 0:
             return response
         else: attempt++
```

When I click a button in my GUI that calls the `command` method, I want the buffer contents to be displayed on a QtLabel as soon as the buffer contents match my requirements.
The problem I now have, is that i use `sleep` to repeatedly check the buffer contents. This blocks the GUI.
I tried using PyQt6's signals and slots, but they don't allow me to **return** the buffer contents, only to call (or connect to) a method that can do a certain thing.
I want to use returns because this provides an easy way to process received data, for example:

```
result = command(0x01, "test")
print(result)
```

Maybe I'm overthinking this and someone knows an alternative solution!

The buffer that I referred to earlier is filled with data from the serial port addressed by QtSerialPort. Maybe I direct connection between the `command` method and QtSerialPort's `readyRead` signal is possible?

Comment: If you want to do a task at specific intervals, use QTimer. *Never* use blocking functions like `time.sleep()` in the GUI.

Comment: If you're using [QSerialPort](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qserialport.html), can't you simply connect a custom slot to `readyRead` and then emit a custom signal from it with the desired result once all the data becomes available? Polling doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Yes I could, but the signal then has to connect to a new method. It can't return the value to the caller, right? Also, I then would have to write a method for every possible command.

Comment: Signals do not have callers, they only have receivers - that's really the whole point of the signal/slot mechanism. You just need a simple asynchronous send/receive API: one method sends `id, payload` and another receives `id, result`. Commonly, this would be backed by a queue. Thus, once `readyRead` has all the data, the current pending item is popped off the queue, a custom signal emits `id, result`, and the next item in the queue is sent. The receiving slot then decides how to handle the result based on the `id` (which could be an enum member, or just a string).

Comment: PS: there's [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75473475/984421) with an accepted answer that uses essentially the same solution as outlined in my comment above. The only real difference is that my solution emits a generic signal rather than switching callbacks.